# Can SPA frameworks be used in MPA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application, web-frameworks

Can frameworks like `react` or `vue` be used in more traditional apps, where server framework render pages as views? If not, which js frameworks can you suggest for MPA?

Comment: yes they can. there's nothing stopping you. theres too many to list and software recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You could of course use Vue js in Application where the backend is responsible for rendering the views. if this is the case then you would use Vue js to make components used in your views rendered by the backend

For instance you want to have a tab functionality then you could use Vue js to achieve it  and then use it in your views